# MongoDB: Update nested field from another nested field with dot notation using MongoShell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I want to update an empty nested field from another nested field value. I'm using this Mongo Shell command:

`db.myCollection.updateMany({"object2.field": ""}, { $set: {"object2.field": '$object1.field' } } );`

But `$object1.field` is not resolved and the destination field actually contains the variable name instead of its content.

I've performed many tests and documentation searches but with no success.

Comment: it can not access another field for internal operation, use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), just need to wrap update part in array bracket `[{ $set: { "object1.field": "$object2.field" } }]`

Comment: It just works. So frustrating to have spent that amount of time for a pair of brackets. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [turivishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8987128/turivishal) said in his comment: Mongo Shell can not access another field for internal operation.
Must use [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/). In this case, just need to wrap update part in array bracket `[{ $set: { "object1.field": "$object2.field" } }]`.